# List of 2 elements to csv

Tags: python

I have been facing an issue parsing an horrible txt file, I have manage to extract to a list the information I need:

```
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'compute-0-4.domain.tld']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'commvault-vsa-vm']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'compute-0-4.domain.tld']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'instance-00000008']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', '/dev/vda']
['hostId', '985035a85d3c98137796f5799341fb65df21e8893fd988ac91a03124']
['key_name', '-']
['name', 'Commvault_VSA_VM']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'compute-0-28.domain.tld']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'dummy-vm']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'compute-0-28.domain.tld']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'instance-0000226e']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', '/dev/hda']
['hostId', '7bd08d963a7c598f274ce8af2fa4f7beb4a66b98689cc7cdc5a6ef22']
['key_name', '-']
['name', 'Dummy_VM']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'compute-0-20.domain.tld']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'mavtel-sif-vsifarvl11']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'compute-0-20.domain.tld']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'instance-00001da6']
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', '/dev/vda']
['hostId', 'dd82c20a014e05fcfb3d4bcf653c30fa539a8fd4e946760ee1cc6f07']
['key_name', 'mav_tel_key']
['name', 'MAVTEL-SIF-vsifarvl11']
```

I would like to have the element 0 as headers and 1 has rows, for example:

```
OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host, OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname,...., name
compute-0-4.domain.tld, commvault-vsa-vm,....., Commvault_VSA_VM
compute-0-28.domain.tld, dummy-vm,...., Dummy_VM
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import re

with open('metadata.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:

        if re.search('hostId|properties|OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host|OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname|name', line):
            re.sub("[\t]+", " ", line)
            find = line.strip()
            format = ''.join(line.split()).replace('|', ',')
            list = format.split(',')
            new_list = list[1:-1]
```

I am very new at python, so sometimes I ran out of ideas on how to make things work.

Comment: Looks like you need to "transpose" the data. That term should be about to help you read for a solution.

Comment: Could you paste the (abbreviated) input file as well, please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uTB0RwU2RpySOVj8HreH5bIUkrmGe3Ft/view?usp=sharing here you go @Tomalak

Comment: Not exactly abbreviated, but still helpful. See below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your input file, I see that it contains what appears to be output from the openstack `nova show` command, mixed with other stuff. There are basically two types of lines: valid ones, and invalid ones (duh).

The valid ones have this structure:

```
'| key                | value                 |'
```

and the invalid ones have anything else.

So we could define that every valid line

- can be split at the `|` into *exactly* four parts, of which
- the first and the last part must be empty, and the other parts must be filled.

Python can do this (it's called unpacking assignment):

```
a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b, c, d = some_string.split('|')
```

which will succeed when the right-hand side has exactly four parts, otherwise it will fail with a `ValueError`. When we now make sure that `a` and `d` are empty, and `b` and `c` are not empty - we have a valid line.

Furthermore we can say, if `b` equals `'Property'` and `c` equals `'Value'`, we have hit a header row and what follows must describe a "new record".

This function does exactly that:

```
def parse_metadata_file(path):
    """ parses a data file generated by `nova show` into records """
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        record = {}
        for line in file:
            try:
                # unpack line into 4 fields: "| key | val |"
                a, key, val, z = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
                if a != '' or z != '' or key == '' or val == '':
                    continue
            except ValueError:
                # skip invalid lines
                continue
            if key == 'Property' and val == 'Value' and record:
                # output current record and start a new one
                yield record
                record = {}
            else:
                # write property to current record
                record[key] = val
    # output last record
    if record:
        yield record
```

It spits out a new dict for each record it finds and disregards all lines that do not pass the sanity check. Effectively this function *generates* a stream of dicts.

Now we can use the `csv` module to write this stream of dicts to a CSV file:

```
import csv

# list of fields we are interested in
fields = ['hostId', 'properties', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'name']

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields, extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(parse_metadata_file('metadata.txt'))
```

The CSV module has a `DictWriter` which is designed to accept dicts as input and write them—according to the given key names—to a CSV row.

- With `extrasaction='ignore'` it does not matter if the current record has more fields than required
- With `fields` list it becomes extremely easy to extract a different set of fields.
- Configure the writer to suit your needs ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)).
- This:

  ```
  writer.writerows(parse_metadata_file('metadata.txt'))
  ```

  is a convenient shorthand for

  ```
  for record in parse_metadata_file('metadata.txt'):
      writer.writerow(record)
  ```

Comment: This works like a charm, I should had started that it was an "nova show" output from openstack, thanks a lot!

Comment: Next time think of putting in more context details and you're good. :) Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a step by step approach to build a 2D array by keeping track of your headers and each entry in the text file.

```
headers = list(set([entry[0] for entry in data])) # obtain unique headers
num_rows = 1
for entry in data: # figuring out how many rows we are going to need
    if 'name' in entry: # name is unique per row so using that
        num_rows += 1 

num_cols = len(headers)

mat = [[0 for _ in range(num_cols)] for _ in range(num_rows)]

mat[0] = headers # add headers as first row

header_lookup = {header: i for i, header in enumerate(headers)}

row = 1
for entry in data:
    header, val = entry[0], entry[1]
    col = header_lookup[header]

    mat[row][col] = val # add entries to each subsequent row

    if header == 'name':
        row += 1

print mat
```

output:

```
[['hostId', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'name', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', 'OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'key_name'], ['985035a85d3c98137796f5799341fb65df21e8893fd988ac91a03124', 'compute-0-4.domain.tld', 'Commvault_VSA_VM', 'commvault-vsa-vm', 'instance-00000008', '/dev/vda', 'compute-0-4.domain.tld', '-'], ['7bd08d963a7c598f274ce8af2fa4f7beb4a66b98689cc7cdc5a6ef22', 'compute-0-28.domain.tld', 'Dummy_VM', 'dummy-vm', 'instance-0000226e', '/dev/hda', 'compute-0-28.domain.tld', '-'], ['dd82c20a014e05fcfb3d4bcf653c30fa539a8fd4e946760ee1cc6f07', 'compute-0-20.domain.tld', 'MAVTEL-SIF-vsifarvl11', 'mavtel-sif-vsifarvl11', 'instance-00001da6', '/dev/vda', 'compute-0-20.domain.tld', 'mav_tel_key']]
```

if you need to write the new 2D array to a file so its not as "horrible" :)

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lines in mat:
        lines_out = '\t'.join(lines)
        f.write(lines_out)
        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd 

list_to_export = [['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'compute-0-4.domain.tld'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'commvault-vsa-vm'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'compute-0-4.domain.tld'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'instance-00000008'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', '/dev/vda'],
['hostId', '985035a85d3c98137796f5799341fb65df21e8893fd988ac91a03124'],
['key_name', '-'],
['name', 'Commvault_VSA_VM'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'compute-0-28.domain.tld'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'dummy-vm'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'compute-0-28.domain.tld'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'instance-0000226e'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', '/dev/hda'],
['hostId', '7bd08d963a7c598f274ce8af2fa4f7beb4a66b98689cc7cdc5a6ef22'],
['key_name', '-'],
['name', 'Dummy_VM'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host', 'compute-0-20.domain.tld'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname', 'mavtel-sif-vsifarvl11'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname', 'compute-0-20.domain.tld'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name', 'instance-00001da6'],
['OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name', '/dev/vda'],
['hostId', 'dd82c20a014e05fcfb3d4bcf653c30fa539a8fd4e946760ee1cc6f07'],
['key_name', 'mav_tel_key'],
['name', 'MAVTEL-SIF-vsifarvl11']]



data_dict = {}

for i in list_to_export:
    if i[0] not in data_dict:
        data_dict[i[0]] = [i[1]]

    else:
        data_dict[i[0]].append(i[1])

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient = 'index').T.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Seems not to work, I tried differents ways using pandas but I am still struggling.

Comment: The code I post above works as intended. Not sure how you only get 0,1? How to do you read your original dataframe / crate your list of lists?

Comment: I made it work, I did not noticed that you nested the stream of lists. It is now okay this is a valid workaround as well.